# Python: IMAP to delete an email

Tags: python, gmail, imap

How would I go about deleting an email or flagging it as seen using IMAP? I have been looking through other posts for quite some time and all of their solutions are failing. Even the python documentation is failing me, below is some example code, the `M.store` line is the solution from the Python documentation. However, this is not working and is not deleting the emails when I go and check the inbox.

```
global number
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
try:
    password = 'password'
    M.login('email', password)
except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
    print "Login Failed"
rv, data = M.select("ALL", "UNSEEN")
if rv == 'OK':
    print "Processing mailbox...\n"
    processEmail(M)
    M.store(number, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
    M.expunge()
    print "Email deleted"
    M.close()
M.logout()
```

Comment: What is number?  You never set it.

Comment: it is gets assigned within processEmail, for the time being assume it is 1.

Comment: Show us the code within processemail, then.

Comment: That is around a 500 line long file, it doesn't need to be included here for context.  But for your information number simply gets the number for the most recent email.

Comment: Well, it is relevant.  Is it the sequence number or the UID?  There are many ways to refer to an email.